# How to change target framework 4.5 to 3.5 vs 2017

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc

How to Lower the project level to NET **4.5** to **3.5** in `vs2017`,
When I change the Framework NET **4.5** to **3.5**, it shows me this problem:

```
Warning Unable to resolve the primary reference "MetroFramework, Version = 1.2.0.3, Culture = neutral, PublicKeyToken = 5f91a84759bf584a, ProcessorArchitecture = MSIL" 
because it has an indirect dependency on the Framework assembly "Microsoft.Build.Utilities.v4.0 , Version = 4.0.0.0, Culture = neutral, PublicKeyToken = b03f5f7f11d50a3a" 
that has not been resolved in the currently targeted Framework. ".NETFramework, Version = v3.5". 

To resolve this issue, remove the reference "MetroFramework, Version = 1.2.0.3, Culture = neutral, PublicKeyToken = 5f91a84759bf584a, ProcessorArchitecture = MSIL", 
or re-apply your application to a version of Framework that contains "Microsoft.Build.Utilities.v4.0 , Version = 4.0.0.0, Culture = neutral, PublicKeyToken = b03f5f7f11d50a3a"
```

Comment: Did you do a clean build after change from 4.5 to 3.5?

Comment: It would be helpful to post the error message in English. I second the clean and rebuild to see if that clears it.

Comment: you need to remove the 4.5 references (for example csharp.dll) and replace the language level specific code with the older equivalent